# How do I append GCP User groups to the JWT Token which is created by my LB/IAP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, terraform, jwt, in-app-purchase

We are currently trying to set up a whole web app with Terraform(GCP), Database (CloudSQL - Postgres), Backend(Python) and Frontend(Vue).

My setup: I have an GAE (standard) which is running the Python frontend. Users, who are signed up to the Google workspace and have enrolled in a certain GCP user group, can access the frontend. This is done with a Load Balancer in combination with an Identity Aware Proxy that checks for a iap-https-resource-accessor role assigned to this user group. This works just fine. But this IAM is to rough.

We want to implement different user groups in our domain and they all should get the accessor role for one but in the end should only be able to see certain data from the CloudSQL via our GAE Python backend.

Our idea was to somehow pass the GCP user group via the IAP as an JWT attribute to the backend GAE. This way we can differentiate the user groups when querying the database. Do you know how this could be achieved?
We read up on sign_in_attributes when using different LogIn providers but as far as we understand, Google will still be the provider when we are using the IAP and people log in with their GCP accounts. We might also be able to make use of some SSO functionalities but that probably won't help right now...